# Why is finally useful in java?

Tags: java, try-catch-finally

I wonder why `finally` is useful after a `try catch` test? In any scenario, the code defined after the `finally` statement will be executed.

What is the difference with these two codes?

```
try{
    int a = 1 / 0;
} catch(ArithmeticException e){
    System.out.print("Hi");
} finally {
    System.out.print("It's me again...");
}
```

and :

```
    try{
    int a = 1 / 0;
} catch(ArithmeticException e){
    System.out.print("Hi");
}
System.out.print("It's me again...");
```

Even if a error is catch, `"It's me again..."` will be displayed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well for starters, if the **`System.out`** stream is closed, and the `catch` block thus raises an exception, then the finally block will still be executed. So the two are **not equivalent**. So in the context of:

```
System.out.close();
try{
    int a = 1 / 0;
} catch(ArithmeticException e){
    System.out.print("Hi");
} finally {
    System.out.print("It's me again...");
}
```

Finally will at least do an attempt to write to `out`. This won't be the case if you write it *after* the `try`-`catch` block.

The `finally` is useful for a couple of reasons:

1. It is usually a possibility that the code in the `try` block raises **another exception that the one specified in the `catch` block(s)**, in that case `finally` will still be executed.
2. if there is a **`return`/`break`/`continue` statement** in the `try` block that has effect outside the `try` block (e.g. a `break` in a `try` in a `for` loop), it will not be executed if you write it after the `try`, then `finally` will also be called. This also results in more elegant code. For instance:

   ```
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));

   try {
       return br.readLine();
   } finally {
       br.close();
   }
   ```

   Notice the `return` statement: if you would do the `close` of the file without a `finally`, it would require you to define a variable, etc. (furthermore if something goes wrong when reading the file, it will of course not close the file).
3. if the **`catch` block(s) on their turn throw an exception**, again finally will be executed.

It also allows you to perform some actions after an exception has been thrown, but without catching the exception: the exception is thrown further if is never catched. In case of:

```
try {
    throw new SomeException("The culprit!");
} finally {
    System.out.println("Some closing words.");
}
```

The constructed `SomeException` and its stacktrace is not "toched" by the `finally` block: the stack trace is not altered. So the bugfixer can find out where the exception has been thrown originally.

In general it is good to write everything that has to be done before leaving the `try-catch` (with zero or more `catch`es) block in a `finally`, since it protects you against all kinds of corner cases.

More into programming language theory, `return`, `break`, `continue`, `throw`, etc. are all code path changing mechanisms. A `finally` statement guards that in case of such behaviour you are protected. If later the designers of Java would introduce a new mechanism your code is still "protected". It is always advisable to use infrastructure a programming language offers since the designers take all these possibilities into account.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

> This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs.

Please note the term **unexpected**. What you showing is expected exception.

Answer (score 0):

The finally block is usually used to do final operations even when some exception appears in the middle of your code.

An example would be to close a file in a finally block.